# How to connect an external data base from dialogflow (GCP)

Tags: dialogflow-es

To summarize the issue, I have an application which has integration with dialogflow. In dialog flow I have configured the intent. For each intent I have created a webhook. 
Wanted to understand if I have to return data from a data base along with the fullfilment  for the intent what will be the best way to do?

Comment: query your database get result, create response and send

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Another questions I have is ,how do I get logged in users email address in a WEBHOOK?